# how to resolve invalid argument error in memset() write() read() in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, beagleboneblack, i2c

I am working on a Beaglebone Black and writing the code for i2c with an IMU in C++

Certainly there would be many read() and write() commands. But everytime Eclipse outputs an error "Invalid argument".

```
int i2c_readbyte(int handle,char buff[],char regaddr){
   // Clear buffer
   memset(buff, 0, strlen(buff));

   buff[0]=regaddr;

   // Write address to handle
   if(write(handle,buff,1)!=1)
   {
       printf("Error:Register not accessible!!\n");
       return(-1);
   }

   // Read byte from handle
   if(read(handle, buff, 1)!=1)
   {
       printf("Error:Content corrupt!!\n");
       return(-1);
   }

   return(1);
}
```

The errors are:
Invalid arguments' int write(int,const void *,?)

Invalid arguments' int read(int,void *,?)

Invalid arguments' void * memset(void *,int,?)

I have seen other answers where in the Provider Settings >> "Check" CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings [ Shared ].

I tried to Index>>Rebuild. No improvement.

unistd.h is included. I tried the exact [example](https://linux.die.net/man/3/write) but it gave the same error. The difference i have noticed is in "buff" datatype. But most I2C comm C++ programs use char array.

Comment: It seems that Eclipse is failing to understand the `size_t` type, but I don't know why. One extra comment: the `memset` call is not required in the above code and it is also very dangerous because of the `strlen`.

Comment: I checked CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings [Shared]. It now seems to work. Only binary execution is not possible. I understand that as it is a cross development for a beaglebone. However a few extra includes were added. On a mac, the xcode includes were added. I have not deployed the code into the BBB, but when i do, is this workaround fine or it is a must the program be "compile-able" via only the arm-linux-gnueabihf. I am new to this hence, my assumption is the code would not compile properly on a BBB with errors as mentioned above. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The Eclipse indexer, although very good, does not necessarily agree with the compiler. In my experience, usually Eclipse is more permissive (it indexes "correctly" code with errors), but there are cases where the code is correct and Eclipse fails to index, perhaps due to some configuration errors, especially when it doesn't understand some symbol (such as `size_t`). Eclipse indexer does support cross-compilation very well, but the defaults are not always sufficient and configuration is tricky. In short: you have to compile to be sure.